# Javascript Game Engine

Tags: library, javascript, game-development

I have learned how to code html, javascript, and css to make simple games (not published but completed). I want to make better games so I have decided to use a game engine. I have an issue with my computer that stops me using unity but I still want to program in javascript or javascript like languages such as UnityScript. The other major game engine that I frequently see is unreal4 but that is c++ only and I don't want to learn a new language.

Can someone please suggest an alternative on the same standard to the mentioned languages that uses Javascript. Also is [unreal.js](https://github.com/ncsoft/Unreal.js) for unreal 4 any good.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Pixi.js](https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js), if you're looking to create a 2D game. It's a library (but still an engine), and has a lot of utils to create your own game

Alternatively, there's [Babylon.js](https://github.com/BabylonJS/Babylon.js), which supports 3D graphics.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Phaser](https://phaser.io/), an open source 2D game framework.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of Unreal.js and my team is using it daily for making a working prototype of next-gen game. :) If you have an experience with making some apps with UE4, you might agree the 'rapid prototyping' and 'live-reloading' is a real your life savior.